# How to disable universal newlines in Python 2.7 when using open()

Tags: python, python-2.7, newline

I have a csv file that contains two different newline terminators (`\n` and `\r\n`). I want my Python script to use `\r\n` as the newline terminator and NOT `\n`. But the problem is that Python's universal newlines feature keeps normalizing everything to be `\n` when I open the file using `open()`.

The strange thing is that it never used to normalize my newlines when I wrote this script, that's why I used Python 2.7 and it worked fine. But all of a sudden today it started normalizing everything and my script no longer works as needed.

How can I disable universal newlines when opening a file using `open()` (without opening in binary mode)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to open the file in binary mode, as stated in the module documentation:

```
with open(csvfilename, 'rb') as fileobj:
    reader = csv.reader(fileobj)
```

From the [`csv.reader()` documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html):

> If *csvfile* is a file object, it must be opened with the ‘b’ flag on platforms where that makes a difference.

In binary mode no line separator translations take place.

Comment: Sorry, I should have clarified. I am opening a csv file. But it is not being read with the `csv.reader()`. It's being opened and read as a normal file, not a csv file object. Does that make a difference? Also, I heard that there is a way to disable the universal newlines in python using `--without-universal-newlines` somewhere. But that's all I know. Do you happen to know anything about that? I would think it would be in a config file somewhere.

Comment: @CM-Dev: then opening the file in binary mode is still the best idea. And why *not* use the `csv` module? Why re-invent that wheel?

Comment: @CM-Dev: note however that the *universal newlines support* feature is *not* normally enabled for file objects accessed with `open()`. You'd have to use the `rU` mode to enable it. See https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0278/. By default it is the standard OS translation for text files that applies.

Comment: It's a long story why i'm not using the `csv` module. But to sum it all up it causes problems with the content in my csv columns and using the standard file read worked (although not now haha). Also, I did see that same page too but for some reason it is enabled and I don't know how or why. I even tried specifying the file mode just in case it was using `rU` as the default for some reason and it still didn't work.

Comment: Sorry if this is a stupid question...but I just found this page discussing `--without-universal-newlines`: [https://docs.python.org/2.3/whatsnew/node7.html](https://docs.python.org/2.3/whatsnew/node7.html) It mentions you can disable the universal newlines by adding that in Python's configure script. Do you know where I can find the configure script?

Comment: @CM-Dev: You need to compile Python from source; `./configure` is the first step in that process.

Comment: @CM-Dev: but let me make it explicit once again: your problem is **not** with Universal Newline support, because that is **not** used with files unless you explicitly enable it by opening with the `U` mode switch.

Comment: Okay bummer, I was hoping to avoid that. Alright, do you know what is causing the `\r\n` line endings to be converted to `\n`? I thought it was the universal newline feature because that's usually what causes the newlines to be normalized. I guess if I have to open in binary mode I will. I was just trying to do it as a text file because it was working just fine before.

Comment: @CM-Dev: opening the file in text mode does that, *depending on the OS*, or specifically, on Windows.

Comment: Just wanted to let everyone know that I solved my problem. @Martijn Pieters is correct about needing to open the file in binary mode. I know in my question I specified that I wanted a solution that didn't require reading in binary mode. But I marked Martijn Pieters answer as correct as it is an appropriate solution. Because what I was wanting isn't exactly possible. I ended up needing to write a function ignore other newline characters and to only recognize a specific newline character as the end of a line. But that along with opening the file in binary mode gave me exactly what I needed.

Comment: Thank you, @Martijn Pieters! I really appreciate your assistance and thorough explanations. You were a big help!